# How can I display an image from a URL on a home screen?

Tags: app-widgets

I want to load an image from a URL and have it get updated regularly from a web page.

Something like a widget that would show my current Stack Overflow flair.  [image: sample so flair]

Another badge/flair example is to show the [weight loss banners](http://www.myfitnesspal.com/badges) at myfitnesspal.com like this:

[image: sample my fitness pal image]

I've tried searching the market for photo widgets, webcam widgets, and URL widgets.   I'm not sure how to get the above image that updates onto my home screen.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This thread goes way back but I still were unable to find one in the market that seems to fit the description, so I made one myself. Get it [here](http://code.google.com/p/url-image-widget/downloads/list):

[image]

The widget updates hourly, and currently there is no way to configure that.

Comment: This works great!

Comment: @Lie Ryan I would love to have this on my ASUS transformer... anything special I need to do to get it to work?

Comment: @DeaconDesperado: not as far as I know, you just need to allow non-market apps installation. I haven't tested it in a tablet-sized screen or anything other than Android 2.2, but I don't expect there to be any problems as the program itself is very simple. Put in a reply in the comment if you need a different aspect ratio or a different widget size.

Comment: @LieRyan Worked as you described.  League of Legends stats banner FTW.

Answer (score 2):

I've implemented that app because I wanted it for myself:

[URL Image Widget](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.weite_welt.urlimagewidget)

Have fun!

Comment: Pls fix link. Dead

Answer (score 0):

I wanted an app to do this, and I wanted it to be professional, reliable, and easy to use, and I wanted to know it would be maintained in future and work with new Android versions. As I run a software business, I decided to make it our next product.

**Showr** supports Android 3.1+, and you can use it as a lock screen widget on Android versions that support that feature. It supports images from RSS or Atom feeds, and from other apps (such as the Gallery) as well as from a fixed URL. It also integrates with some websites, such as Tumblr and Stack Exchange. Unlike the accepted answer to the question, you can set how often it updates, and it has a Smart Updating feature to save battery life and network use.

[Download Showr **free** from Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shadowburst.showr&referrer=ase15356), or [see Showr on StackApps](https://stackapps.com/questions/3997/showr-for-android).

Answer (score -2):

You might need a very specific widget that is coded to retrieve some data from the said web page in a specific format (XML, JSON, API calls, etc.,) then parse and display it.

For example, a quick Google [search](https://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&q=android%20flair%20widget) for "android flair widget" brings back [this](https://stackapps.com/questions/2160/soflair-an-android-widget-that-shows-your-flair) app.  You need only to provide the user's ID (e.g. http://api.android.stackexchange.com/1.1/users/3646 for my profile,) and it polls the stackoverflow.com servers once every hour and retrieves the "flair".

Comment: I'm looking for something that works for non-stack overflow sites as well.

Comment: There probably isn't a "magic bullet" app that would work on every site.  You will need a custom solution.  First, the site itself needs to be specifically coded to provide information you are looking for via some sort of an interface (RSS, XML, JSON, API, etc.) Then the app/widget would have to be coded to retrieve this info (simple polling or more advanced push), make sense of it and display it.

Comment: I'm looking to use the published interface for stack overflow flair and for myfitnesspal sites which is a url to an image file.